# Path exists in sys.path but still gives module not found error in Python

Tags: python

So, I print the `sys.path` in the python terminal inside the working python project directory, and find the directory there. I've also put in a `__init__.py` in the directory, too.

But when I do a `import directoryname`, I get a module not found error.

Where can I possibly be going wrong?

Ok, I found the problem. It is giving a no such directory error when I check the $PYTHONPATH.

This is my PythonPath

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/python/softwares/orade

Comment: Do you happen to have some variable or class with the same name as the module you want to import?

Comment: Nope, I don't. The structure is as simple as this appname/lib/apps. I'm currently in the appname directory, in the python shell. I'm not able to import appname.

Comment: Are you __sure__ that the case matches and that there are no Unicode characters that ___look___ the same in the directory name?

Comment: Does this only happen from the interpreter, or with a script too? Have you used any `virtualenv`s recently? Does the directory with the module have weird permissions?

Comment: We will need more information to debug this, did you try to isolate your code to a very simple example demonstrating the issue? Are you using any special conditions we should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, I checked again. Removed everything from the library apart from the __init__.py file. Still no luck. Should my $PythonPath be path/to/the/directory or path/to/the/directory/ ?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Have edited to show the current problem.

Comment: @Hick the directory is not a module; it's a package; you need to import a specific module from within the package.

Comment: I understand that. The problem happens, when I do something like this: from package import module. Here, package is the directory name and I get a no such module error.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are trying to import the `orade` module. `PYTHONPATH` represents the path to the directory that contains python modules, not the collection of paths to the modules.

So you should put the parent directory of your module in the `PYTHONPATH`. If the path to your module is `/home/python/softwares/orade`, you should put `/home/python/softwares` in your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/python/softwares
```

And then you should be able to do:

```
>>> import orade
```

If the `orade` directory contains a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I thought that the python path separator was ; rather than : - I _might_ be wrong.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Path separator is OS dependant. It's `;` on Windows and `:` on POSIX systems. Since the OP uses forward slashes in his paths and `export`, I assumed he works on a POSIX system.

Comment: I get a no such file or directory for PYTHONPATH. I'm quite sure the path exists.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and when I check my PYTHONPATH by doing $PYTHONPATH on the command prompt, it is showing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/python/softwares no such file or directory

Comment: @Hick You should check it using: `echo $PYTHONPATH` :) Typing just `$PYTHONPATH` tries to run it. But it seems that you have set it correctly. Can you import the module now?